# Cause: Command execution failed on the local server with non-zero exit code

Tags: plesk, plesk-onyx

Failed to fetch information from target servers
Cause: Command execution failed on the local server with non-zero exit code.

```
  command: /usr/local/psa/bin/ipmanage --xml-info
exit code: 255
stdout: <ipinfo>
<ip name="193.160.214.57">
<state>0</state>
<type>shared</type>
<ip_address>193.160.214.57</ip_address>
<mask>255.255.255.255</mask>
<iface>venet0</iface>
<clients>0</clients>
<hostings>0</hostings>
<ftps>false</ftps>
<publicIp></publicIp>
</ip>
</ipinfo>

stderr: [2019-10-20 21:21:51.133] ERR [util_exec] proc_close() failed ['/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/f2bmng' '--reload'] with exit code [1]
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PleskUtilException: f2bmng failed: 2019-10-20 21:21:51,115 fail2ban.jailreader [17670]: ERROR No file(s) found for glob /var/log/secure
2019-10-20 21:21:51,115 fail2ban [17670]: ERROR Failed during configuration: Have not found any log file for ssh jail
ERROR:__main__:Command '['/usr/bin/fail2ban-client', 'reload']' returned non-zero exit status 255 in /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/Service/Agent.php:210
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/Ip/Ban/Manager.php(490): Service_Agent->execAndGetResponse('f2bmng', Array, '')
#1 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/Ip/Ban/Manager.php(458): Ip_Ban_Manager->_callUtility('--reload')
#2 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/Fail2Ban/EventListener.php(123): Ip_Ban_Manager->reload()
#3 [internal function]: Plesk\Fail2Ban\EventListener->applyChanges()
#4 {main}
thrown in /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/Service/Agent.php on line 210

That is a critical error, migration was stopped.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is "wrong" with your plesk (not so familiar with), but fail2ban error is pretty simply:

> `ERROR No file(s) found for glob /var/log/secure`
>   `2019-10-20 21:21:51,115 fail2ban [17670]: ERROR Failed during configuration: Have not found any log file for ssh jail`

Your `ssh` jail seems to be configured to monitor `/var/log/secure` which is not exist. Either you have to specify proper `logpath` (`/var/log/auth.log`?) where ssh logs authentication errors;
or if it is systemd journal on your system, you have to specify `backend = systemd` for that.

Related fail2ban jail.local would be:

```
[ssh]
# backend = systemd
logpath = /var/log/auth.log
```

But you can surely configure this in plesk settings too.

Also note your jail is called `ssh`, where normally original default jail of fail2ban is `sshd` (but it could be indeed configured with this name from your maintainer).